# Conceptual question on Cauchy's Theorem on Groups (abelian case)

Tags: abstract-algebra

The theorem states that let G be a finite abelian group and p be a prime. If p divides the order of G, then G has an element of order p.

The proof given is this: 
We first prove the special case that where G is abelian, and then the general case; both proofs are by induction on n = |G|, and have as starting case n = p which is trivial because any non-identity element now has order p. Suppose first that G is abelian. Take any non-identity element a, and let H be the cyclic group it generates. If p divides |H|, then a|H|/p is an element of order p. If p does not divide |H|, then it divides the order [G:H] of the quotient group G/H, which therefore contains an element of order p by the inductive hypothesis. That element is a class xH for some x in G, and if m is the order of x in G, then xm = e in G gives (xH)m = eH in G/H, so p divides m; as before xm/p is now an element of order p in G, completing the proof for the abelian case.

I can't see why we need the condition of prime here. Which part of the proof uses that property. From what I see, it applies to all numbers. Thanks

Comment: The base case does not hold if $p$ is not prime, for instance $\mathbb{Z}_6$ has an element 3 of order 2.

Comment: it's used to prove the induction base, where you say "... which is trivial since any non-identity element now has order $p$."

Answer (score 1):

Already in "...which is trivial because any non-identity element now has order p" because for example $\mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/2$ no element has order $4$.

Comment: my lecturer gives me another proof that uses this base case:
n = 1 is vacuously true, because there is no prime divisor of 1. Does that mean this this cannot be a correct base case since i need base case of order p?